# For VS Code how to download IntelliCode models externally and install them manually

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have run VS Code on an air-gapped machine (no internet). I was able to download externally the (Java) extensions I need and then install them manually.

Java development works now. However now after opening a JavaScript file (as part of a Java Web project) I get the following error "*Couldn't download IntelliCode model. Please check your network connectivity or firewall settings*":

[image]

So I need to download the relevant model externally on another machine and then install it manually into VS Code.

I couldn't find anything about this in the VS Doco. How do I do this?

Comment: You can reach out to the authors of extensions on GitHub and see whether they have suggestions. VS Code documentation won't help on such specific cases.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the tip. Reaching out to the authors of extensions sounds good. Here on StackOverflow I was just hoping somebody in the SO community knows about this problem...